# In C++11 or above, Is there a way to implement a single-method pure virtual C++ interface by lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a large scale C++ library written in C++ 98, which heavily uses C++ interface (precisely, C++ classes with only pure virtual functions) for event handling. Now seeing that my code are compiled by C++11/14 compiler, I'm thinking if I can reduce boilerplate code by using C++11 lambda to replace interface implementation.

In my library, there are some C++ interfaces who have only a single method, for example, the following interface us used to define a simple task:

```
class SimpleTask
{
public:
    virtual void run() = NULL;
};
```

My intention is to use C++ lambda to replace the old single-method interface implementation code like this:

```
void myFunction()
{
    ...

    class MySimpleTask : SimpleTask //An inline class to implement the iterface
    {
    public:
        void run() 
        {
            //Do somthing for this task
            ...    
            delete this;    //Finally, destroy the instance
        }
    };
    MySimpleTask * myThreadTask = new MySimpleTask();
    Thread myThread(L"MyTestingThread", myThreadTask);
    myThread.start();

    ...
}
```

In Java 8, [we can use Java lambda to implement a single-method interface](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html#lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-interface-implementations) to write code more concise than using anonymous class. I did a bit research in C++11 and found there nothing similar to this.

Since my library's event handling code is designed in object oriented pattern, not in functional coding style, is there way to use lambda to help reduce those single-method interface implementation code?

Comment: there is really no reason for the Java tag

Comment: There's no need for `new`. Pass it by move or at least make a `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: `SimpleTask` isn't an interface.  There is no virtual method, let alone a pure virtual method.

Comment: If you are going to modernize existing C++ then you should use modern techniques. C++ has changed since 1998 when interfaces and virtual functions were a big thing. The more (use the term loosely) common technique is to use templates and duck typing. If the object passed has the appropriate interface you can use it. For Lambda the interface is functor like i.e. `operator()(<Argument List>)`.

Comment: `I did a bit research in C++11 and found there nothing similar to this` Except maybe C++ Lambda? `[<CaptureList>](<ArgList>){<Code>}` Most fun declaration in C++ is `[](){}();`

Comment: The problem is that lambdas are designed to work with `std::function<void()>`, rather than `SimpleTask`.

Comment: Thanks for all input / suggestions. The code I had were originally written back in 2005, and there are tons of better C++ patterns I can adopt, such as use C++ smart pointer instead of "new", it takes time to modernize the whole library.

Comment: Sorry, the "run" method should have signature "virtual void run() = 0;", I made it wrong when I write the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a wrapper, e.g.:

```
class SimpleTask {
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

// This class wraps a lambda (or any callable) and implement the run()
// method by simply calling the callable.
template <class T>
class LambdaSimpleTask: public SimpleTask {
    T t;

public:
    LambdaSimpleTask(T t) : t(std::move(t)) { }

    virtual void run() {
        t();
    }
};


template <class T>
auto makeSimpleTask(T &&t) {
    // I am returning a dynamically allocated object following your example,
    // but I would rather return a statically allocated one.
    return new LambdaSimpleTask<std::decay_t<T>>{std::forward<T>(t)};
}
```

And then to create the task:

```
auto task = makeSimpleTask([]() { });
Thread myThread(L"MyTestingThread", task);
```

Note that you still need to have a wrapper and a `makeXXX` function for each one of your interface. With C++17 and above, you can get rid of the `makeXXX` function by using class template argument deduction. Getting rid of the wrapper is not possible but you might be able to reduce the boilerplate code by encapsulating some stuff in macros.

---

Here is an example macro (not perfect) that could be used to reduce the boilerplate code:

```
#define WRAPPER_FOR(C, M, ...)                       \
    template <class T>                               \
    class Lambda##C: public C {                      \
        T t;                                         \
    public:                                          \
        Lambda##C(T t) : t(std::move(t)) { }         \
        virtual M { return t(__VA_ARGS__); }         \
    };                                               \
    template <class T> auto make##C(T &&t) {         \
        return Lambda##C<std::decay_t<T>>{std::forward<T>(t)}; }
```

And then:

```
class SimpleTask {
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class ComplexTask {
public:
    virtual int run(int, double) = 0;
};

WRAPPER_FOR(SimpleTask, void run());
WRAPPER_FOR(ComplexTask, int run(int a, double b), a, b);
```

Comment: As `SimpleTask` is referred as an example interface, your answer would be complete if it was passed as template argument, not hardcoded. Edit adjustment: and only proper `makeXXX` functions were to be implemented.

Comment: @R2RT Agree, but I doubt all interfaces match `void run()`. I've added some details at the end of the answer.

Comment: Oups, right. One last note: shouldn't `t` be moved in constructor and `makeSimpleTask`?

Comment: It should ;) And it should also be forwarded in `makeXXX`.

Comment: `WRAPPER_FOR` could take the name of the method, and deduce arguments from the type of `&C::M`, then forward to the lambda.  And yes, that covers the dangerous bit.  It gets annoying with `&` `&&` `const` `volatile` `noexcept` overloads tho.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I would be interested in how you do that for `WRAPPER_FOR`... I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I think it makes code slightly more concise. I can not have through understanding on all your code (particularly the Macro part) but I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 4):

Isn't it what you are looking for?

```
std::thread t(
  [](){
    std::cout << "thread\n"; // Here is the code run by the thread...
  }
);
std::cout << "main\n";
t.join();
```

Comment: Perhaps show where the `//Do somthing for this task` bit would go in your version to make it a bit clearer

Comment: Not really. Java let's you write anonymous class definition inline, when calling method. So in this case Java code would look e.g. like this: `registerTask(new SimpleTask { void run() { \\run; }});`. `std::thread` is completely unelated to the question.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen OP explicitly mentioned the need for lambda, not anonymous class.

Comment: OP seems to have his own `Thread` class, which accepts `SimpleTask` pointer in its constructor. Not sure how this answer is related

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès They mentioned the Java lambda, asking whether something similar could be done in C++

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The thread example is just one of many "event handler" or callback design in my library. So adopting std::thread did not answer my question. Appreciate it anyway. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Old Virtual interface style:

```
struct MyInterface {
    virtual Type action(argList)  = 0;
};

class MyClassThatUsesInterface
{
    MyInterface&   interface;
    public:
        MyClassThatUsesInterface(MyInterface& ref)
            : interface(ref)
        {}
        Type doStuff(argList)
        {
             return interface.action(argList);
        }
};
...
MyInterfaceImplementation injectedInterface;
MyClassThatUsesInterface  worker(injectedInterface);
...
worker.doStuff(someStuff);
```

More Modern style:
Or Duck Typing Style:

```
// No need for an explicit interface definition.
// Any function that will work can be used
// Let the compiler decide if the used function (functor/lambda) works.

template<typename F>
class MyClassThatUsesLambda
{
    F   interface;
    public:
        MyClassThatUsesLambda(F&& ref)
            : interface(std::move(ref))
        {}
        Type doStuff(argList)
        {
             return interface(argList);
             // Will compile if the type F supports function like operations.
             // This means a:
             //   * function pointer.
             //   * std::function
             //   * A type the overloads operator()
             //   * Lambda
        }
};
template<typename F>
MyClassThatUsesLambda<F> make_MyClassThatUsesLambda(F&& f) {return MyClassThatUsesLambda<F>(std::move(f));}
...
auto  worker = make_MyClassThatUsesLambda([](argList){/* Some Stuff*/});
...
worker.doStuff(someStuff);
```

Looking at your example (Which is obviously not C++ by the way)

```
// Added C++ required virtuals etc:
// Some basic memory management (not checked).
class SimpleTask
{
    public:
        virtual void run() = 0;
};
// Guessed at this object.
class Thread
{
    std::string                    name;
    std::unique_ptr<SimpleTask>    task
    public:
        Thread(std::string const& name, std::unique_ptr<SimpleTask>&& task)
            : name(name)
            , task(std:move(task))
        {}
        void start() {
            task.run();
        }
};
void myFunction()
{
    class MySimpleTask: public SimpleTask
    {
        public:
            virtual void run() override
            {
                //Do something for this task
                ...
                // Destroying this is an exceptionally bad idea.
                // Let the owner destroy it.
                // I made the task hold it as an std::unique_ptr
                // To solve this.    
                // delete this;    //Finally, destroy the instance
            }
    };
    ...
    Thread myThread("MyTestingThread", std::make_unique<MySimpleTask>());
    myThread.start();
    ...
}
```

Now lets re-write using duck typing:

```
template<typename F>
class Thread
{
    std::string                    name;
    F                              task
    public:
        Thread(std::string const& name, F&& task)
            : name(name)
            , task(std:move(task))
        {}
        void start() {
            task();
        }
};
template<typename F>
Thread<F> make_Thread(std::string const& name, F&& f) {return Thread<F>(name, std::move(f));}
void myFunction()
{ 
    ...
    auto  myThread = make_Thread("MyTestingThread", [](argList){/* Do something for this task */});
    myThread.start();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, I need to update my modern C++ knowledge before I can completely understand your solution, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do @Holt's excellent answer with a bit better syntax.  It is not complete, because there is boilerplate to do.

```
template<class C, class M = decltype(&C::run)>
struct run_as_lambda_impl;

// non-const non-volatile non-ref qualified noexcept(false) case:
template<class C, class R, class...Args>
struct run_as_lambda_impl<C, R(C::*)(Args...)>: C {
  std::function<R(Args...)> f;
  R run(Args...) final override {
    return static_cast<R>(f( std::forward<Args>(args)... ));
  }
};
```

You'll need 3 ref qualifies, times 2 const qualifies, times 2 volatile qualifies, times noexcept true/false for a total of 24 different versions of this.

now imagine a macro:

```
#define RUN_AS_LAMBDA_TYPE( CLASS ) \
  run_as_lambda_impl< CLASS >
```

this hard codes `run` as the method we override, but does not hard code the signature.  Also we type erase the lambda, but I'm ok with that for now.

We can get around this.

```
#define BASE_LAMBDA_TEMPLATE( NAME, METHOD ) \
  template<class C, class M = decltype(&C::METHOD)> \
  struct NAME

#define LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, QUALS ) \
  template<class C, class R, class...Args> \
  struct NAME<C, R(C::*)(Args...) QUALS> : C { \
    std::function<R(Args...)> f; \
    NAME( std::function<R(Args...)> fin ): f(std::move(fin)) {} \
    R METHOD(Args...) QUALS final override { \
      return static_cast<R>( f( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) ); \
    } \
  }

  #define LAMBDA_TEMPLATE( NAME, METHOD ) \
    BASE_LAMBDA_TEMPLATE( NAME, METHOD ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, & ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, && ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, const ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, const & ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, const && ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile & ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile && ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile const ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile const & ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile const && ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, noexcept(true) ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, & noexcept(true) ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, && noexcept(true) ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, const noexcept(true) ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, const & noexcept(true) ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, const && noexcept(true) ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile noexcept(true) ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile & noexcept(true) ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile && noexcept(true) ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile const noexcept(true) ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile const & noexcept(true) ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, volatile const && noexcept(true) )
```

which is 24 different `LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL` calls for the 3*2*2*2*2 types of method overrides.  You could reduce this:

```
#define LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_C( NAME, METHOD, QUALS ) \
  LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, QUALS ); \
  LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL( NAME, METHOD, const QUALS )

#define LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_CV( NAME, METHOD, QUALS ) \
  LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_C( NAME, METHOD, QUALS ); \
  LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_C( NAME, METHOD, volatile QUALS )

#define LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_CVR( NAME, METHOD, QUALS ) \
  LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_CV( NAME, METHOD, QUALS ); \
  LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_CV( NAME, METHOD, & QUALS ); \
  LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_CV( NAME, METHOD, && QUALS )

#define LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_CVRE( NAME, METHOD ) \
  LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_CVR( NAME, METHOD,  ); \
  LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_CVR( NAME, METHOD, noexcept(true) )
```

Then:

```
  #define LAMBDA_TEMPLATE( NAME, METHOD ) \
    BASE_LAMBDA_TEMPLATE( NAME, METHOD ); \
    LAMBDA_TEMPLATE_IMPL_CVRE( NAME, METHOD )
```

which is 3+3+3+3+4 = 16 lines instead of 24.

---

Suppose you have these two interfaces:

```
class SimpleTask {
public:
  virtual void run() = 0;
};

class ComplexTask {
public:
  virtual int do_stuff(int, double) = 0;
};
```

then you can write

```
LAMBDA_TEMPLATE( LambdaRun, run );
LAMBDA_TEMPLATE( LambdaDoTask, do_task );
```

and we can use `LambdaRun<SimpleTask>{ []{std::cout << "I ran\n"; } }` as a lambda-based implementation of `SimpleTask`.

Similarly, `LambdaDoTask<ComplexTask>{ [](auto a, auto b) { return a+b; } }`.

---

This isn't very Java-like.  Java is a far more OO-centric language than C++; in C++, OO design is an *option*.

C++ lambdas create invokable objects that override `operator()`.  If you have something that is "can be run with a signature", the idiomatic way to do it in C++ is to use a `std::function<void()>` or similar.

`std::function` uses value semantics; internally you can store a pointer within the value if you want.

So in C++ you'd want:

```
using SimpleTask = std::function<void()>;
```

and the rest of your code is now trivial:

```
Thread myThread(L"MyTestingThread", []{ /* code */} );
myThread.start();
```

because the lambda can be directly converted-to a `std::function<void()>` if the signatures are compatible.

A part of this is migrating to value-semantics.

But barring that, you'll want to

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions!